# networkx draw separate nodes to left and right side - graphviz, python

Tags: python, networkx, draw, graphviz

I use the following code to colour the nodes that start with "n" as gray and the nodes starting with "m" letter with red colour

```
color_map = []
    for node in c:
        strnode = str(node)
        if strnode.startswith("m"):
            color_map.append('red')
        else:
            color_map.append('gray')

    nx.draw(c, pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(c, prog='circo'),node_size=140,  scale= 2,  node_color=color_map,with_labels=True)
```

This works successfully as the picture shows below:

[image]

However, I have tried to draw the graph as a bipartite graph, meaning all the Red nodes to be aligned on the left side and all the gray nodes on the left side with no success. Any ideas?

*Fixed with @Mohammed Kashif answer, however the right side notes cannot displayed all:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bipartite_layout` defined in NetworkX. You can read more about it [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout.html). You need to pass a list of nodes belonging to either of the sets of the bipartite layout.

Below is the working example which uses the `bipartite_layout`. I took the liberty of defining the nodes of the Graph similar to yours.

```
import networkx as nx

# Define the nodes of the Graph
nodes_list = ["m1", "n1", "m2", "n2", "m3", "n3", "m4", "n4"]

# Define the Graph and add the nodes/edges
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes_list)
G.add_edges_from([("m1", "n3"), ("m2", "n1"), ("n4", "m3")])


color_map = []

# This will store the nodes belonging to one set of 
# the bipartite graph. In this case, the nodes which
# start with "m"
one_side_nodes = []

for node in G:
    strnode = str(node)
    if strnode.startswith("m"):
        color_map.append('red')
        # Add the node to the list
        one_side_nodes.append(node)
    else:
        color_map.append('gray')

# Now in the `pos` attribute pass in nx.bipartite_layout,
# with the list of nodes belonging to one set of the bipartite
# graph, i.e. one_side_nodes.
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.bipartite_layout(G, one_side_nodes),node_size=140,
        scale= 2, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True)
```

Here is the output:

[image: Bipartite Layout]

**References:**

- [NetworkX: Bipartite Layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout.html)

You can also view the code on Google Colab Notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K2uGOOtbXTls6EbeVJTFgt_ocSXlvISZ?usp=sharing).